# -fortran : reading numbers from a text file

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a text file of numbers containing several columns and several lines. I have tried several ways including arrays but in the best result I could get only 3 columns of the whole. Any ideas how I can read all the data in Fortran 77?

```
open(unit=1, file='f', status='old')

do i = 1, 100
    read(1, *) x(i), y(i), z(i)
    write(6, * ) x(i), y(i), z(i)
enddo
```

or even 2 dimensional arrays:

```
do i = 1, 100
    do j = 1, 50
        read(1, *) x(i, j)
        write(6, *) x(i, j)
    enddo 
enddo
```

or changing the `open(..., access='direct')`

none of them worked out since i have a file like this:

```
1 2 4.5 77 89 4 3 2...
2 4 4 5 6 73 5 3.4 ...
1 2 4 5  67  8 99...
...
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code!

Comment: Downvoted because the question is badly presented and not explicitly asked. For example, what do you mean by "read all the data" (read which data, and into what kind of data structure?), "the best result I could get" (what result?). (Please don't answer here in the comment section. Instead, make direct edits your question to make it clearer. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data does not seem to have any particular structure.
You can use list-directed input for this:

```
  program main
  real a(100)
  read (*,*) a
  print *,a
  end
```

I would advise you against using any unit number smaller than 10 in your code for your own purposes.

Comment: it worked with some modifications. thanks a lot tkoenig!